# How to configure an AKS cluster to use secrets from external Vault installed on different AKS Cluster

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks, hashicorp-vault

I have two kubernetes clusters running on Azure AKS.

- One cluster named APP-Cluster which is hosting application pods.
- One cluster named Vault-Cluster which the Hashicorp Vault is installed on.

I have installed Hashicorp Vault with Consul in HA mode according to below official document. The installation is successful.

https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/vault/kubernetes-minikube?in=vault/kubernetes

But I am quite lost on how to connect and retrieve the secrets in Vault cluster from another cluster. I would like to use the sidecar injection method of Vault for my app cluster to communicate with vault cluster. I tried the follow the steps in below official document but in the document minikube is used instead of public cloud Kubernetes Service. How do I define the  "EXTERNAL_VAULT_ADDR" variable for AKS like described in the document for minikube? Is it the api server DNS address which I can get from Azure portal?

https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/vault/kubernetes-external-vault?in=vault/kubernetes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you interact with `Vault` is via HTTP(s) API. That means you need to expose the `vault` service running in your `Vault-Cluster` cluster using one of the usual methods.

As an example you could:

- use a service of type [`LoadBalancer`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#loadbalancer) (this works because you are running kubernetes in a cloud provider that supports this feature);
- install an [ingress controller](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/), expose it (again with a load balancer) and define an `Ingress` resource for your `vault` service.
- use a [node port](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#nodeport) service

The `EXTERNAL_VAULT_ADDR` value depends on which strategy you want to use.

Comment: Hi @whites11, thanks a lot for your answer. Is it possible to recreate the vault service with internal load balancer annotation? This way I can get an IP which will be recognized in all Azure so that it can be reachable from the other app-cluster? I don't want to use any method which will assign a public IP to vault service since I will only use the vault internally.

Comment: Absolutely, azure supports internal load balancer: Take a look here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/internal-lb#create-an-internal-load-balancer

Comment: I tried to recreate the service as Internal Load Balancer and it worked. Now vault service is reachable within Azure Network. Thanks a lot @whites11 !

Comment: My pleasure @Casca

Comment: Hello again @whites11, sorry for asking multiple questions here. Now I have problem with authentication between app cluster and vault cluster. I followed the steps in the below document. But somehow the authentication is unsuccessful. The error message is "auth.handler: error authenticating: error="context deadline exceeded". I am writing the api server address of the app cluster which I get from Azure AKS service as kubernetes host while configuring the access. Do you think it's correct?

https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/vault/kubernetes-azure-aks?in=vault/kubernetes

Comment: I am no vault expert, but `context deadline exceeded` makes me think of a low level network error such as a firewall issue or wrong/unreachable network address.